# Relacionar y Mostrar datos de mas de una Persona en c# Windows Form y SQL

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este programa, la verdad tengo muchos problemas  a la hora de crear la base de datos y como entrelazarla porque en si hay 6 personas en el casamiento , y cuando lo creo necesitaria llamar a esas 6 despues , sus datos estan en una tabla llamada Personas pero no quiero que se repitan esos datos nuevamente en la tabla Matrimonio ,la idea seria cuando toco un casamiento que se cargen los datos de la esposa y esposo y sus respectivos padres ,como podria crear tablas para eso?

Comment: Con una relación a la tabla persona

Comment: Como se podria crear esa relacion,la verdad no se me ocurre el problema es que puedo crear un casamiento ID y que esas 6 personas tengan el mismo casamiento id pero despues nose como diferenciarlas o llamarlas bien

Comment: Tendrías que explicar mejor el problema, porque la verdad es que no lo entiendo bien.  Recuerda que los que te leemos no sabes absolutamente nada de tu problema, ni de que estas haciendo, ni para que lo estas haciendo y ni como lo estas haciendo. También debes tener claro que para que podamos responder, la pregunta debe estar escrita de un modo que se ajuste a lar normas

Comment: Hay una chance de que te lo pueda explicar mejor en una llamada de discord?

Comment: No estimado, ni a mis clientes les acepto explicaciones no escritas. Pero créeme que te entiendo, se que es difícil poder explicar un problema en texto. Una buena pregunta (en forma y en fondo) toma bastante tiempo escribirla

Comment: El tema seria que yo Ingreso los datos de esas 6 personas, ahora las guardo en La tabla Matrimonio( nose que datos guardar en ella sin repetir todo porque sino serian muchas columnas minimo 18) , por lo que intento es crear algun tipo de relacion entre esas 6 personas , ejemplo Matrimonio ID entonces yo busco en la tabla Matrimonios el ID 1 Y tendrian que salirme el DNI de esas 6 personas,casamiento 1 ,dni padre madre esposo esposa etc , como hago para diferenciar cual es cual dado que todos tienen matrimonio ID 1 y despues al tocar el Matrimonio ID 1 en el gridview se cargen los datos al view

Comment: Creo que necesitas una tercera tabla, una que relacione las tablas `Matrimonio` y `Persona`, en esa 3ra tabla solo tienes 2 columnas: la Id (PK) del matrimonio y la otra es la ID de la Persona. Luego para obtener todos los datos debes hacer un `join` de SQL

Comment: Lo unico que necesitas en la tabla `Matrimonio` son 7 columnas: ID, DNI Novio, DNI Novia, etc.  Solo guarda el DNI de cada persona en la columna adecuada y luego lo relacionas con la tabla `Personas`

Comment: @alanfcm y si fueran 30 personas, necesita 31 columnas y con 300??

Comment: Si el objeto `Matrimonio` necesitara 30 personas con 30 diferentes atributos la respuesta es si.